# Vagrant error "The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found..." windows 10 downloader exit status 3221225781

Tags: vagrant-windows

I'm getting this error on Windows 10:

```
The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error:
```

Note that there is no expanded error message, this makes it different from the other similar questions that have been posted. It also has a different solution.

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be caused by a missing dependency when running vagrant 1.8.1 on Windows 10. It happened for me under windows command line "cmd.exe" and under git-bash. This was also reported and closed on the mitchellh/vagrant GitHub repo as ["On Windows 10, "vagrant up" and "vagrant box add" throw blank errors #6852"](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6852)

I and others worked around this by installing the "[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)" as suggested by jeremywhittington in issue [#6754](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6754).

A relevant snipped of the "vagrant --debug add hashicorp/precise32" output shows "curl" exiting with a strange code that doesn't get propagated to the standard vagrant output:

```
...
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\HashiCorp\\Vagrant\\embedded\\bin/curl.EXE", "-I", "-q", "--fail", "--location", "--max-redirs", "10", "--user-agent", "Vagrant/1.8.1 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.2.3)", "--continue-at", "-", "-H", "Accept:application/json", "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 3221225781
 WARN downloader: Downloader exit code: 3221225781
ERROR warden: Error occurred: The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error:
...
```

Comment: this also works on Windows 8.1; [Issue #6725: Adding a local box via "box add" fails with v1.8.0, succeeds with v1.7.4](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6725) seems to be the relevant issue in that case

Comment: while using win 8.1 with vagrant 1.8.4 just install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328 has solved my issue.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me on a fresh install of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood was that the vagrant installs by default a version of CURL that causes a conflict with Windows 10 .

I managed to solve the problem as follows:

1) Download a new CURL:

[https://sourceforge.net/projects/curlforwindows/?source=typ_redirect]

2) Extract the folder to c:/

Ex: C:/curl-7.4.0/

3) Find the vagrant folder C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin

4) Rename the file curl.exe to curl.exe_ or delete.

5) Add the c:/curl-7.4.0/ to the {PATH} variable.

6) Open the prompt and test the command 'curl --help'

7) Run again the 'vagrant up' command and be happy :)